# Xamarin WinPhone 8 Project unavailable in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: windows-phone-8, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.winphone

I'm working on a Xamarin cross platform project. There is a Android and WinPhone 8 project yet. Everything worked fine. Now I moved to project to another PC. I'm working with Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2015 community version.
I installed the Windows Phone SDK 8 and tried to load the project in Visual Studio. The Android project is ok but on the WinPhone project there is written (unavailable) in the project explorer but the files are in the correct directory.

[image]

[image]

I also tried to install a Windows Phone 8 SDK update but I always get the message "It needs Visual Studio 2013 or Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 to install this". I also installed Visual Studio 2013 but still get the message.

Did I miss something to install? Already tried to Repair Visual Studio 2015 but it's still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved the problem. It's so ridiculous. The SDK and Visual Studio have to be the same language. Otherwise it will not work... well played Microsoft, well played...